# Why is it necessary for SortedSet's equals method to break the Set contract?

Tags: java, set

[`SortedSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) is an implementation of `Set<T>` that maintains an ordering over elements of type `T`.

I'm struggling to see why it was necessary to implement `SortedSet`'s `equals` method in such a way that it breaks `Set`'s general contract, as per the documentation below:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See the `Comparable` interface or `Comparator` interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

#### Current implementation

From browsing through the source code, it seems equality for `SortedSet` currently works in the following way. Given two `SortedSet` instances `a` and `b`, `a.equals(b)` will:

- Delegate comparison to [`AbstractSet#equals(Object o)`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSet.java#L85)

  - Check for nullity, casting problems and make sure sets are of equal size
- Call [`AbstractCollection#containsAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L323)

  - Loop over all elements `e` in `c` and call `this.contains(e)` for each.
- Dispatch to specific `Collection#contains(Object o)`implementation, for example [`TreeSet#contains`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java#L233).
- Taking `TreeSet<T>` and its backing `NavigableMap<T>` (usually `TreeMap<T>`) as the canonical example, we can see the call falls through to [`TreeMap#containsKey(Object key)`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java#L230).

  - This checks if `TreeMap#getEntry(key)` is not `null`.
- Crucially, this is what that code looks like:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            p = p.left;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            p = p.right;
        else
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### Intuitive `SortedSet` equality

To determine if two SortedSet instances `a` and `b` are equal, I would personally:

1. Do the same initial checks in the current implementation, such as size comparisons
2. Start a cursor on the first element of set `a`
3. Start a cursor on the first element of set `b`
4. Compare the element with its own `equals` method
5. Move both cursors to the next element and go to step 4 until elements are exhausted.

Since the sort order is guaranteed by a `Comparator` or a `compareTo` method, I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

#### Question

- Is there an issue with my approach above?
- If not, why wasn't `SortedSet` equality designed in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You are only considering `sortedSetA.equals(sortedSetB)`.

`sortedSetA.equals(hashSetA)` should also return true if the elements are the same, even if the traversal order is different.

> **Set::equals**
>
> Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have
>   the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in
>   this set

That is why the implementation follows a general case.

Far from adhering to the contract, your implementation also breaks `Set`'s contract because two sets with the same elements sorted in different ways would be deemed unequal.

Comment: I never claimed my own implementation adheres to the `Set` contract - but thank you for your answer, this makes a lot of sense. If I want the functionality to compare two `SortedSet` instances in the way I suggested, does this mean I have to code it myself then?

Comment: @PaulBenn You asked "why does it have to break the contract?" and provided an alternative implementation. I thought the implication was supposed to be that your implementation does not break the contract. Yes, you will have to write it yourself. I checked Guava and Apache Commons - the most likely places for such a util method - and neither has what you describe.